# Run Configuration Error: There is nothing to run in compound configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I have 4 Spring Boot applications and I decided to create a workspace to use single window for all of them. I created an **Empty Project** then added my projects via *File -> New -> Module from Existing Sources*. All looking good but when I add configuration **Run/Debug Configurations**, *Compound*, and click the (+) to add I got empty selection "Nothing to show" and an error message below "Run Configuration Error: There is nothing to run".

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-203.5981.155, built on December 1, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.9+11-b1145.21 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
```

Answer (score 0):

You add to Compound Run Configuration other Run Configurations which **were created previously**. Please check [Create compound run/debug configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/creating-compound-run-debug-configuration.html).